# How to set transparent Activity in android 6.0

Tags: java, android

I have a Activity,and I set it's launchMode is singleInstance. now I set it's background transparent .but when I start it in setting ,it's background is black.
so ,what should I do.below is my code

in style:

```
<style name="translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/translucent_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
 <itemname="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
</style>
```

in androidManifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".main.activity.AssisTipsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/translucent"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want transparency on a custom color then adjust the alpha.... set the background property of viewgroup by adding this line ...

```
android:background = "#88FFFFFF"
```

this would make the background semi transparent. The 88 represents the alpha... Ranging from 00 to FF .. Replace "FFFFFF" with the custom colorcode that you want .  If that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `parent="Theme.AppCompat"` to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"`

Comment: I don't have 'Theme.AppCompat.Translucent' theme I use api23

Comment: can you try : `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>`